# How to Add (F1) key Function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I want to display `Hello` when I press the `F1` key.

```
shortcut.add("F1",function(){
      alert("Hello");
});
```

But the problem is when I *pressed* `F1` it brought me to a new tab. Is there any way to disable this default feature? but I'm not really sure about this `code` if it's working on `F1` *keypress*. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe on keyup event and check event code. Therefore, onkeydown/up keyCode always holds the key code. onkeypress you can find the actual character the user typed by evt.charCode || evt.keyCode.
https://javascript.info/keyboard-events